# Xming: why JFrame lost focus when it is setUndecorated(true)?

Tags: java, focus, putty, jwindow, xming

I have strange situation: when I starting some java application on remote computer via Putty + Xming - and if `JFrame` is `setUndecorated(true)` - it can not gain focus again if it was lost:

```
jFrame.setUndecorated(true);

jFrame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener(){

            @Override
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
               System.out.println("Window gained focus");
            }

            @Override
            public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
               System.out.println("Window lost focus " + e.getOppositeWindow());//e.getOppositeWindow is null
            }

});
```

When started - undecorated `JFrame` receives focus, but if it is clicked somewhere - the focus is lost and the opposite window is `null`. Then it never gain focus again. The problem do not exists if `setUndecorated(false)` - when `JFrame` is decorated.

Answer (score 2):

It's Xming software bug. Downloaded MobaXterm - and everything works fine now even with undecorated JFrames. Also tried Putty + X11 MobaXterm server - works good. That proves that Xming here is the problem.